# Set the ClassName with state value in modular css in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using modular css in react. I have to addClass to a `<h2>` how do I do that the problem is I am using modular css I know how to do it in normal css.Please Help.
Here is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from '../css/MessageHeader.css';


class MessageHeader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name : "name"
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(

            <div className={style.container}>
                <div className={style.iconWrapper}>
                    <i className ="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div className={style.profileWrapper}>
                   <h2 className={this.state.name}>john appleseed </h2> //this is how I would in normal css 
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MessageHeader;
```

Comment: if you could explain what is really happening i could be more precise with the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help you add the className this way. Variable is any variable in state with classname

```
    <h2 className={`${this.state.variable}`}></h2>
```

Comment: should I add {this.state.variable} ??

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: let me explain say for example i need a classname to be set after a condition is executed and the classname is a variable that i have declared in state so i can use  it to set the className as above

Comment: if you dont want to change className in the future just add like as you add in html tags className="classname"

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a global class, I'm assuming you also want the h2 classes to be scoped to that component. Just like your other classes, you need to reference the `style` import - but use a dynamic key based on the state, like so:

```
<h2 className={style[this.state.name]}>john appleseed </h2>
```

Then your css module `MessageHeader.css` should contain a class for all names that you want to custom styling for.

Example:

```
.container {
  // some styles here
}

.johnAppleseed {
  color: yellow;
}

// You can also specify a name as a child of the container just like normal css,
// although it's not really necessary
.container .bobBobbert {
  color: red;
}
```

Keep in mind that if your name in the state has spaces, that isn't going to work for a css class name, so you'll have to do some transformation (e.g. `this.state.name.replace(...)` to remove spaces and/or punctuation.